# Can anyone tell me why this program fails?

Tags: cipher, steganography

> ```
>  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@1f6d27cc was empty
>     ScalaTestFailureLocation: SorterTest at (SorterTest.scala:75107)
>     org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@1f6d27cc was empty
>         at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:6597)
>         at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException$(Assertions.scala:70102)
>      at org.scalatest.FunSuite.newAssertionFailedException(FunSuite.scala:75107) 
>      at org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper.macroAssert(Assertions.scala:6597)
>         at SorterTest.$anonfun$new$4(SorterTest.scala:72104)
>      at SorterTest.$anonfun$new$4$adapted(SorterTest.scala:6597)
>      at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:84116)
>      at SorterTest.$anonfun$new$3(SorterTest.scala:69101)
>         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:83115)
>         at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:77109)
>         at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:69101)
>      at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:6698)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:69101)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:6799)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:6597)
>         at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:85117)
>         at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:83115)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:69101)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:73105)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:72104)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:6597)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:84116)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike.runTest$(FunSuiteLike.scala:69101)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTest(FunSuite.scala:75107)
>         at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:6597)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:70102)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:75107)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:6597)
> ```

Why is this program failing?

Hint:

> I've tried to duplicate the code but I got the same problem...

Comment: I tried to run my test but it just fails...

Comment: Is this a puzzle?

Comment: Maybe... This is my first post :c

Comment: welcome to PSE! sorry but this doesn't seem on-topic here, for the uses of this website, feel free to look up at the help centre. posting irrelevant questions here may result in receiving downvotes and having the question closed. for this question, maybe [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/] can help?

Comment: I really think this should be here, just read it carefully ;P

Comment: Voting to close, needs [mcve]  ;)

Comment: This is a cipher puzzle, just a bit different ^^

Comment: I just love how this looks like a bad StackOverflow question yet it still blatantly looks like a puzzle

Comment: I really like this puzzle. Well done!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The program is failing because:

> Kafka Hates You

It would seem that:

> The feeling is mutual.  Taking the ascii value of the numbers at the end of the error messages yields: KAFKA HATES ME BECAUSE I HATE KAFKA.

Comment: That's it!! It was my first puzzle so it maybe was too easy, I'll try to create a harder one :P

Comment: @Turvo don't forget about the "many eyes" effect - sometimes puzzles seem artificially easy because it was solved quickly, but don't forget that there were also 1500+ people who did _not_ solve it.

Comment: Knowing nothing about Scala - would those normally be line numbers?  I feel like in any programming language if your line numbers get into 5 digits, you're doing something wrong.  I was instantly suspicious of that, especially the 80+ thousand numbers...

Comment: You are right, those numbers are suspicious. I've used uppercase letter's ascii code followed by lowercase letter's because using just 2 or 3 numbers would be too easy (That's why the hint mentioned "duplicated code")

Answer (score 15):

To solve it in the spirit of the riddle, we run:

> grep -o ':.*)' < input | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | xargs node -e "console.log(process.argv.slice(1).map(x => parseInt(parseInt(x.slice(2)) > 122 ? x.slice(1) : x.slice(2))).map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join(''))"

which provides us with the reason:

> kafkahatesmebecauseihatekafka

So it is unlikely that the problem will be resolved soon...

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.

Comment: You can also do this by evaluating `String.fromCharCode(...document.querySelector("#question code").textContent.match(/:\d+/g).map(s=>s.slice(3)))` in the web console.

Comment: I love your answers! Nice job!

Comment: `fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/80670?&site=puzzling&filter=withbody").then(f=>f.json().then(r=>console.log(String.fromCharCode(...r.items[0].body.match(/:\d+/g).map(s=>s.slice(3))))))` is another approach.

Comment: Pipe stack trace into `perl -lne 'if (/\:(\d\d)(\d+)\)/) { print chr($1) . " " . chr($2)}'`